# Pass attribute value via params to new user with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, parameters

I am working on a referral system for my webpage. Until now I created a devise user with a 1-to-1 self-refered association.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :create_ref

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :accounts
  has_one :referel, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
  belongs_to :referer, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

This user gets a unique referral number `ref` that gets included in the referral link that he can share with his friends. The routes look like this

```
get   '/join/:ref' => 'devise/registrations#new'
post  '/join/:ref' => 'devise/registrations#create'
```

Now if user a has ref 1340 and user b opens `/join/1340` I am able to get the right number via `params[:ref]` which leads to user a again. But i am not sure how to set the user_id of user b to `User.find_by_ref(params[:ref]).id` on new or create action.

I already created the devise controllers for registration but I have no idea how to alter the new method in the right way.

I also tried to call a instance method in the user model with `before_create` but when I call the create method the url will change before I can use the params.

Any ideas on this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working now with a little workaround. Not totally happy about this but its a start...

I am working with sessions now in my application controller to save the `ref` from my params and put it into a hidden form field. Looks like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :capture_ref

   private

   def capture_ref
     session[:ref] = params[:ref] if params[:ref]
   end
```

Its working well like this but I dont think its very lean since this method gets fired on every action even though I only need it on registration. Also I dont like to work with hidden field since it could sometimes be a security problem so I will try to put that into my model.